# Passing array data through textures in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

So i'm trying to pass a bunch of vectors to the fragment shader and apparently i should do it with a 1d texture. But if i try to access the passed vectors, the values are not what i expect.

How should i index the texture() function?

Passing the texture:

```cpp
std::vector<vec3> triangles;
//triangles is already filled by this point
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture);        
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB16F, Object::triangles.size(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &Object::triangles[0]);

GLint textureLoc =  glGetUniformLocation( getId(), "triangles" );
glUniform1f(textureLoc, 0);

setUniform((int)Object::triangles.size(), "triCount");

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
//draw a rectangle from -1,-1 to 1,1
```

fragment shader code:

```c
uniform sampler1D triangles;
uniform int triCount;

struct Triangle{
            vec3 a,b,c;
            vec3 normal;
};

void main(){
  for(int i = 0;i < triCount;i++){//for each triangle
    Triangle triangle;
    //set the points of the triangle
    triangle.a = vec3(texture(triangles,i));
    triangle.b = vec3(texture(triangles,i++));
    triangle.c = vec3(texture(triangles,i++));
    //set the normal vector of the triangle
    triangle.normal = vec3(texture(triangles,i++));

    //then i do stuff with the current triangle and return a color 
  }
}
```

The array contains 3 points and a normal vector of a bunch of triangles, that's why i read from the texture this way.

edit:
glGetTexImage confirmed that the passed texture is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`texture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texture.xhtml), the texture coordinates are floating point values ​​in the range [0.0, 1.0]. Use [`texelFetch`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml) to perform a lookup of a single Texel from texture with integral texture coordinates in the range [0, width):

```c
triangle.a      = texelFetch(triangles, i*4,   0).xyz;
triangle.b      = texelFetch(triangles, i*4+1, 0).xyz;
triangle.c      = texelFetch(triangles, i*4+2, 0).xyz;
triangle.normal = texelFetch(triangles, i*4+3, 0).xyz;
```

Be aware, that the computation of the Texel indices in your shader code is incorrect.

---

Alternatively, you can calculate the texture coordinate by dividing the index by the width of the texture. The size of a texture can be get by [`textureSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureSize.xhtml):

```c
float width = float(textureSize(triangles, 0));
```

```c
triangle.a      = texture(triangles, (float(i*4)+0.5) / width).xyz;
triangle.b      = texture(triangles, (float(i*4)+1.5) / width).xyz;
triangle.c      = texture(triangles, (float(i*4)+2.5) / width).xyz;
triangle.normal = texture(triangles, (float(i*4)+3.5) / width).xyz;
```